# Copy second array into first array with particular index

Tags: java, arrays

I need a code to copy the second array into the first array at a particular index accepted from user 
Note : Solution should be without using new array.

For example, **sample input**:

```
int[] arrayOne=new int[50]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
int[] secondArray={10,11};
```

After getting **index** as **3** from user, **expected output will be**:

`arrayOne={1,2,3,10,11,4,5,6,7};`

Thanks

Comment: And what have you tried so far? Where do you stuck? Or this is a "I don't know where to start" question?

Comment: a definite home assignment question

Answer (score 3):

`System.arraycopy(secondArray, 0, arrayOne, 3, 2)` does what you want.

Comment: it does use another array in the background ;)

Comment: No it doesn't – it just copies the underlying memory.

Comment: But wait, you're both right. From the file "System.java" it only uses a buffer if the input and output arrays are different, and even then maybe not. But I'm not a word lawyer. I have a jpg showing this, but i can't figure out how to put it on this page. Anyway look at the source code file ../jdk1.6.0_20/src/java/lang/System.java"

Comment: The documentation explicitly states "...the copying is performed as if the components at positions srcPos through srcPos+length-1 were first copied to a temporary array..." note the "as if". It has nothing to do with different arrays, it is just a way of saying that if System.arraycopy is used to copy data within the same array, it will not overwrite data it would copy later.